# How can I link an HTML file using Angular.js with a controller?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, mean-stack

I'm trying to build an app module using the MEAN stack and I'm using MVC. So I have a folder called AppModules and inside it I have a folder called search and inside that, I have 3 folders, models, views and controllers. I wrote an HTML file in the views folder. Also, in the controllers folder I have a simple function that just outputs something to the console. Now how do I link both of these together?

I watched a MEAN stack tutorial and the person in the video was writing the HTML file in the index.html file of the project, which is what the server automatically opens. I am working on this project with other people, so to avoid conflicts, none of us are writing in the index.html file now. We split our tasks to modules and each person has his own module. So how can I let the HTML file that I wrote be the one that opens without copying all the code to index.html and how can I link it to the controller in the controllers folder?

In the video I saw, the index.html file included something like this: (modified to my own file names)

```
<script src = "../AppModules/search/controllers/SearchBoxController.js"></script>
```

But when I try to use that I just get an error in chrome saying the file is not found, even though that should be the correct path. Is what I'm doing even remotely correct or is there a simpler way?

**EDIT**: I accidentally pasted the HTML tag I used when I was testing. Edited the post with the HTML tag I should have written in the beginning. Still doesn't work. Even when I copy my code to index.html and change the path of the src I still can't get it to work.

Directory structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is with your path name. Try `controller/SearchBoxController.js` or `./controller/SearchBoxController.js`

Comment: But controller is not in the same directory, I have to go one folder up to reach it.

Comment: `index.html` should reside in the root directory. everything else should reside within this folder (nested folders or not). I don't think you can access the upper folder of `index.html`.

Comment: @Swailem95 can you provide your directory structure?

Comment: @xagos Edited my post.

Comment: The issue is that index.html can't access anything outside of the public folder. This is for security sake, as you wouldn't want a hacker to access the private contents of your server. You need to move your angular code into public

Comment: @xagos I tried copying SearchBoxController.js to the public folder and changing the src in index.html to just "./SearchBoxController.js". Now I'm not getting an error, but I'm not seeing a console log that I should be seeing. Also is there another way other than moving my code to the public folder?

Comment: I meant you should bring the entire folder, so bring the search folder in. Otherwise your not going to have access to any of your other angular files

Answer (score 1):

The src you specified in your script tag is saying go to the parent folder of index.html and inside that look for the folder controller. Is your index.html file in the same folder as controller? If not you need to set the relative path right.

Comment: I wrote the wrong HTML tag when I wrote the post, I edited my post with the one I should have written in the beginning, which also doesn't work.

Comment: Since now you uploaded your file structure. The src path should be ../../AppModules/search/controllers/searchBoxController.js

Comment: That still doesn't work. Even when I copied my whole code to index.html.

Comment: ignore the above comment I gave. If AppModules is in the root of your web application use src='AppModules/search/controllers/searchBoxController.js'